# ElasticSearch custom score script does not preserve array ordering

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch with a function_score property to retrieve documents sorted by createdOn. The createdOn field is stored as an Array representing date values, i.e.

```
"createdOn": [ 2014, 4, 24, 22, 11, 47 ]
```

Where createdOn[0] is year, createdOn[1] is month, createdOn[2] is day, etc. I am testing the following query, which should return documents scored by year. However, the doc['createdOn'] array does not preserve the value of the elements. In this query, doc['createdOn'].values[0] returns 4, not 2014.

```
POST /example/1
{
  name:"apple",
  createdOn: [2014, 8, 22, 5, 12, 32]
}

POST /example/2
{
  name:"apple",
  createdOn: [2011, 8, 22, 5, 12, 32]
}

POST /example/3
{
  name:"apple",
  createdOn: [2013, 8, 22, 5, 12, 32]
}

POST /example/_search
{
  "query":
  {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "query": { 
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script_score" : {
          "script": "doc['createdOn'].values[0]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It appears that this is due to the way ElasticSearch caches data: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Accessing-array-field-within-Native-Plugin-td4042848.html:

The only apparent solution other than using the source method (which is slow), is to use nested queries. Any ideas on how I could rewrite my query using nested queries? It seems like the only efficient way to sort this query by year.

> The docFieldDoubles method gets it's values from the in memory
>   structures of the field data cache. This is done for performance. The
>   field data cache is not loaded from source of the document (because
>   this will be slow) but from the lucene index, where the values are
>   sorted (for lookup speed). The get api does work based on the original
>   document source which is why you see those values in order (note- ES
>   doesn't the parse the source for the get api, it just gives you back
>   what you've put in it).
>
> You can access the original document (which will be parsed) using the
>   SourceLookup (available from the source method) but it will be slow as
>   it needs to go to disk for every document.
>
> I'm not sure about the exact semantics of what you are trying to
>   achieve, but did you try looking at nested objects? those allow you to
>   store a list of object in a why that keeps values together, like [{
>   "key": "k1" , "value" : "v1"},...].